# Is there a way to break a piece of dialogue into components?

Tags: natural-language-processing, reference-request, dialogue-systems

In many chatbots, I've seen a lot of hardcoded responses, but nothing that allows an AI to break a piece of dialogue into components (say that the speaker sounds happy or is trying to be manipulative) and model a response based on this.

I envision a coding scheme for different core components of conversation. This would allow an AI to be more dynamic in its responses, and would be closer to actually being able to hold a conversation.

I'm *not* looking for AI-generated text, at least not in the sense of some NN or the like being fed a diet of literature and seeing what it spits out - there's nothing dynamic about that.